# Vue.js 3.0 - Two-Way Data Binding with Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm writing a Vue.js app using Vue.js 3.0. I'm using this as a way to learn the Composition API. One of the features I loved about Vue.js 2.0 was the ease of the two-way data-binding. However, with the Composition API, it's unclear to me how to use it. Especially when a global state is used. For example, my app has two components as shown in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sbutc8q/). The code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-vue" class="demo">
  <banner :class="{ 'even-banner': isEven, 'odd-banner': !isEven }"></banner>
  <hr />
  <content :class="{ 'even-content': isEven, 'odd-content': !isEven }"></content>
  <pre>value={{value}} isEven={{isEven}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const store = {
  state: Vue.reactive({
    result: null
  }),
  generateNewValue() {
    this.state.result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
};

const MyApp = {
  setup() {
    const isEven = Vue.computed(() => store.state.result % 2 === 0)
    const value = Vue.toRef(store.state, 'result')
    return {
      isEven,
      value
    }
  }
}
const myApp = Vue.createApp(MyApp)

myApp.component("banner", 
  { 
    template: '<button @click="onGenerateClick">generate</button>',
    setup(props) {
      console.log('setting up...');
    },
    methods: {
      onGenerateClick() {
        store.generateNewValue();
      }
    }
  }
);

myApp.component("content", {
  template: '<div style="padding:2rem;">' +
    '<div>Enter Value: <input type="text" v-model="result" /></div>' +
    '<br /><div>or</div><br />' +
    '<div><button @click="onGenerateClick">generate</button></div>' +
    '</div>',
  methods: {
    onGenerateClick() {
      store.generateNewValue();
    }
  }  
});

myApp.mount('#my-vue')
```

**CSS**

```
.even-banner {
  background-color:navy;
  color: #fff;
}

.even-content {
  background-color:blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.odd-banner {
  background-color:maroon;
  color:#fff;
}

.odd-content {
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

The idea is pretty simple: If a number is even, use blue backgrounds. If the number is odd, use red backgrounds. I have a generate button which works as desired. However, this small app has a text field that you can manually enter a value in. That value is currently *NOT* changing the background as desired. It's like two-way binding isn't working.

How do you get two-way data binding to work with a global state in a Vue.js app that uses the Composition API?

Answer (score 0):

Your text input isn't binding to the store value, it just references a non-existent data property called result.
try injecting the store into the component, then adding getter/setter to bound property

```
myApp.component("content", {
store,
  template: '<div style="padding:2rem;">' +
    '<div>Enter Value: <input type="text" v-model="myAmount" /></div>' +
    '<br /><div>or</div><br />' +
    '<div><button @click="onGenerateClick">generate</button></div>' +
    '</div>',
    computed:{
        myAmount:{
      get: function(){return store.state.result},
      set: function(val){store.state.result = val}
      }
    },
  methods: {
    onGenerateClick() {
      store.generateNewValue();
    }
  }  
});
```

btw my setter is a quick hack, you wouldn't normally update the store.state property directly, but it should get you started

Comment: Thank you. Your response confirms my assumption though. As soon as you bring in a global state, two-way binding goes away. Instead, you always have to write some intermediary code. The "normal", recommended way would be to have some setter method in the `store` itself.